# Turtle module doesn't open window

Tags: python, python-turtle

I have an exercise at school where we have to use the `sys` module to read a script file that contains instructions for the `turtle` module.
The script file is a `.trtl` file.

**It contains the following info, formatted as below:**

```
Walk
100
Turn
90
Walk
50
Turn
90
Walk
100
Turn
90
Walk
50
```

**I have tried this code:**

```
import sys
import turtle


for idx, line in enumerate(sys.stdin):

move = 0

while (idx % 2) == 0:
    move = line


while (idx % 2) != 0:
    if line == "Walk":
        forward(move)

    elif line == "Turn":
        left(move)
```

when I try running this code with stdin from the script file, my terminal just goes to the next line without doing anything. I can see, that the program is running, and can `KeyboardInterrupt` it, but no window appears.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried printing out your lines (with something like `print(f'->{line}<-')` in order to see what the exact value of the line is? That can help you determine if there is a hidden character that you're not noticing at the *end* of your *line*. ;-)

Comment: @blackbrandt   I think I see, what you mean. I now put a 'line = line.rstrip()' in the loop, and now the window opens! Thank you! Turtle still doesn't move, though.

Comment: There were a few too many issues for me to comment on, so I have added an answer with all of the fixes.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue stems from two main problems:

1. Reading a line from a file will read the ENTIRE line, including the new line character at the end. Using [`.rstrip()`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/rstrip.html) method will remove that.
2. Reading a line from a file reads a string. You have to coerce it to the type that you need. For example, when you read the line `100`, you are reading in 4 bytes: `'1', '0' '0' '\n'`, not the number 100. You will need to add an `int()` coercion as well as strip the trailing `\n` to these lines.
3. Read up on the difference between an `if` and a `while` statement. An `if` statement will check the logical value of its argument, and decide whether or not to execute the following block of code. A `while` loop will *loop* through the code as long as the logical statement is `truthy`.

There are several other issues with your code, which I will indicate in comments.

Fixing your code:

```py
import sys
import turtle

for idx, line in enumerate(sys.stdin):
    #Strip trailing character
    line = line.rstrip()
    #Change if to while
    if (idx % 2) == 0:
        #Coerce value to int instead of string
        move = int(line)
    # idx % 2 will either be 0 or not 0, no need to check twice.
    # If it is not 0, then this else statement will run
    else:
        #Now that line has been stripped of trailing chars, we can check
        
        if line == "Walk":
            forward(move)
        #Alternately, we can use
#       if line.startswith("Walk"):
        # and not have to do an rstrip
    
        elif line == "Turn":
            left(move)
```

Answer (score 0):

For fun, an alternative to @blackbrandt's detailed solution (+1) that, although terse, is also more easily expanded to additional monadic operators:

```
import sys
import turtle

commands = {'Walk': turtle.forward, 'Turn': turtle.left}

for command, argument in zip(sys.stdin, sys.stdin):
    if method := commands.get(command.rstrip()):
        method(int(argument))

turtle.exitonclick()
```

[image]

Comment: Found the functional programmer. This feels like a [CodeGolf.se] entry ;)